# List All Running SQL Anywhere *Servers*, by name (and version?)

Tags: c#, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'd like to be able to get a list of all running Sybase SQL Anywhere v10-16 database servers' names (and versions).

**Is there a "built in" way to do this (preferably in C#)?**

I'm considering finding all running SQL Anywhere server processes and then pinvoking to pull the Caption/Window Title out of one of the process' main window (unfortunately, process.MainWindowTitle doesn't work, at least not when the server is started as hidden).

Comment: Presumably your not making the servers register with LDAP? If not I think the only way would be to attempt port 2638 connections to all hosts - this is what I believe the dblocate utility does (which you could execute and capture).

Comment: I'd like to find all running SQL Anywhere servers, even those that have started up with `-sb 0` (http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbadmin_en11/sb-database-dbserver.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in C#. There is a `dblocate_servers_ex` function ([documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1101/en/dbprogramming_en11/db-locate-servers-ex-esql.html%2ad5e29695)) that you can use from a C/C++ application, or you can spawn the dblocate utility and capture the output, but that's about it.

The dblocate utility, FYI, does not make any TCP connections. It sends out broadcast packets which SQL Anywhere servers respond to, and then lists the responses.

Note that the point of the `-sb 0` switch is to *make* it impossible to find the server using dblocate. If it were possible to find it anyway, the switch would be useless.

*Full disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: OK, so checking running processes windows' captions sounds like it will be the easiest way then.

Comment: Does DBLOCATE list out IQ Databases from any computer on the network or from the computer on which the command is executed?

Comment: DBLocate will list servers it finds from anywhere on the *local* network - any computer that can receive UDP broadcasts from the computer where it's executed. Computers on the other side of switches, bridges, etc. will not receive the broadcast packets and so servers running on those machines will not respond.

Comment: @GraemePerrow Thanks much for the reply. But DBLOCATE doesn't have a switch that restricts the enumeration from the same computer where the command is executed. Is it right? "-s" could be used to specify local machine name but my attempts didn't show the IQ Databases running.

Comment: The `-s` switch filters the servers found by *server* name (i.e. the name of the database server), not machine name. You can pass a parameter to dblocate that's a machine name or IP address, i.e. `dblocate 127.0.0.1` which will filter the responses by machin ename. FYI you can get more help with SQL Anywhere on sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com. Then you're not relying on how often I happen to check StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the forum @GraemePerrow . 
I tried with 127.0.0.1 & 0.0.0.0 and both didn't work. But DBLOCATE <Actual IP Addr> worked in giving out local results.